# Foreign Key Constraint Error in Laravel Migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, database-migration

I have searched numerous questions on this error and cannot seem to fix it no matter what i try.
This is my error:

Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `urls` add constraint `urls_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

My url table is as follows, i require the user_id column to reference `id` on the `users` table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('urls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('full_url');
            $table->string('short_url')->unique();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My original error was - '1452 cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails' so I did php artisan migrate:refresh as i cannot see where the foreign key fails.

Comment: which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: "_Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table_" You don't have a column `user_id` in your `urls` table/migration

Comment: I am using Laravel 9

Answer (score 1):

You have added the foreign key, But you didn't add the field itself.

So you should add:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

to urls table.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doc has a simpler version to create foreign keys.

Doc Link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

```php
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
});
```

This came in laravel 7+

Comment: I have just tried this                                                                      
            Schema::create('urls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('full_url');
            $table->string('short_url')->unique();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });                                                                                                                                        The error is the same?

Comment: as @brombeer said. you don't have `user_id` in `urls` table you need to create the column then assign foreign key on it

Comment: The column is created though,
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();